# apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin' . unable to build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to implement my first sceneform application.
I'm following the following tutorials:

***My references***:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsOU6EOcj51cEDYpCLK_bzo4qtjOwDWfW

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart

I'm using the following configurations:

mac os High Sierra - Version 10.13.6 (17G7024)
Android Studio - 3.1.3

**My app's gradle file**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myfirstapp.example.com.helloar"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // Provides ArFragment, and other UX resources.
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.11.0'

    // Alternatively, use ArSceneView without the UX dependency.
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.11.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'

sceneform.asset('sampledata/ArcticFox_Posed.obj',
        'default',
        'sampledata/ArcticFox_Posed.sfa',
        'src/main/assets/ArcticFox_Posed')
```

**My project's gradle file**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.11.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My manifest file** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myfirstapp.example.com.helloar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- "AR Required" apps must declare minSdkVersion ≥ 24 -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" />


    <!-- Indicates that the app requires ARCore ("AR Required"). Ensures the app is
         visible only in the Google Play Store on devices that support ARCore.
    -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I right clicked on .obj file and clicked on import sceneform asset. It's throwing the adding the following to my app's gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'

sceneform.asset('sampledata/ArcticFox_Posed.obj',
        'default',
        'sampledata/ArcticFox_Posed.sfa',
        'src/main/assets/ArcticFox_Posed')
```

**Error Given**:

> Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant.getMergeResourcesProvider()Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskProvider;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Kindly help with the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded my android studio to 3.4.2 and it's working now.